# how to create a spark v2 table with spark sql?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

use spark.sql create a table in hive metastore

```sql
CREATE TABLE db_test.table_test (
  name STRING,
  status STRING,
  field1 BIGINT,
  field2 BIGINT,
  data_dt STRING)
USING parquet
PARTITIONED BY (data_dt)
LOCATION 's3://somebucket/db_test.db/table_test';
```

then if i try to drop the field1 and field2,

```sql
alter table db_test.table_test
drop columns(field1, field2)
```

then got error `Error in query: DROP COLUMN is only supported with v2 tables.`

> ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMNS statement drops mentioned columns from an existing table. Note that this statement is only supported with v2 tables.

yes the [Spark SQL Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-alter-table.html#drop-columns) also says same, but it's not clear how to create a v2 table or convert an existing table to a v2 table.  even what is a v2 table is not clear.

Comment: What's the spark version you are using?

Comment: spark 3.3.0 on EMR 6.8.

Comment: It's more the API as part of the release of Spark that you have.

Comment: Question confuses 2 issues in fact.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to transform your table from flat to transactional format.

```sql
ALTER TABLE db_test.table_test SET TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');

ALTER TABLE db_test.table_test DROP COLUMNS (field1, field2);
```

Source -> [Cloudera doc](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/using-hiveql/content/hive_alter_a_table_from_flat_to_transactional.html)

Comment: got error "Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to alter table. The table must be stored using an ACID compliant format (such as ORC): db_test.table_test` and i am using parqet,

Comment: Parquet is considered as non-ACID compliant format. However, the alteration you are trying to perform requires the table to be stored using an ACID compliant format, such as ORC. Try to create a new table with the TBLPROPERTIES transactional set to true, deep copy into the new table the data from the first table, delete the first table and then rename the new table to the first table name.

Answer (score 0):

You need this approach using delta format, not parquet.

```
%sql
ALTER TABLE table_test SET TBLPROPERTIES (
   'delta.columnMapping.mode' = 'name',
   'delta.minReaderVersion' = '2',
   'delta.minWriterVersion' = '5')
alter table table_test

drop columns(field1, field2)
```

Comment: we are not on delta or iceberg, just curious when will these DataSourceV2 be used? https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/v2/parquet/ParquetDataSourceV2.scala

Comment: Suggest you move to delta. @DynoFu